# Horizontally expanding JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree, jtreetable

It may seem a little bit strange, but is there a way to make the last node of JTree expand horizontally rather than vertically?
My vertical tree nodes represent different discussion subjects (politics, culture, etc.) and each of those nodes has a list of Article objects. I really need to sort these articles by publication date and place them in the last tree node horizontally.

I hope I was clear, any help or a link is very appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: don't quite understand how that should look like - do you have a screenshot or sketch or point to any standard application with such a beast? Or (guessing from your treetable tag) something like a treeTable where only one node has column data?

Answer (score 2):

You would have to override the `paintComponent()` method for `JTree` and calculate when you were painting the last node. If you were, you would reposition the start point of the painting for the `JLabel` which I believe represents a leaf.

Regards,

Guido

**Edit**

From Sun:

> Swing programs should override
>   paintComponent().

Located on this Page: http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/

Comment: high density of incorrectness: a) never override paint b) there is no concept of "SomeComponent represents a leaf"

Comment: @Kleo: I have overridden paintComponent() myself in the past for projects I am not sure where this rule is enshrined. And b) I am not sure where you are quoting from. I am sorry my answer did not make sense to you but I don't feel that your response and down vote were appropriate. I am always happy to have my answers improved upon.

Comment: Thanks you, that seems a bit tough for me :). I will try it today. I was thinking maybe I could somehow embed a table to the last node. Yes, it is leaf.